# Indian e-Visa asks for date (required) of last issue of Indian Visa-it was 30 years ago. How to find it or get around it?

Tags: visas, india

I have no idea how to find my Visa date or number from years ago. It states that I must have the full date of issue, it won't let you just give a year.

It seems to be okay to put unknown in the Visa number field, but the date of issue, MM/DD/YYY is a required field.

Can anyone help? I see this question all over my google search but no one seems to know so far.

Comment: I seriously doubt that even the Indian authorities have access to these records. Either put down 1/1/yyyy or don't mention the visa at all.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend mentioning the visa. After all, you don’t want to not mention it and then be refused if they uncover this information.

> What I suggest to do is to:
>
> 1. State correctly that you have been issued a visa before, and been to India.
> 2. State "Yes. See attachment 1" in "Have you ever visited India?" question.
> 3. Add a document titled "Attachment 1" where you explain that your previous passport with Indian visa and travel details is not returned to you, and thus you do not have those details. State the year where you been issued a visa, and a year when you visit, if you remember. This should be enough.